# what is the value of 5/3 in mod Z7 (modulo 7)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What is $5x^4 / 3x^2$ in set of integers with modulo $7$($\Bbb Z7$). I got $2x^2$ but I don't think it is the correct one because $2x^2 * 3x^2$ gives $6x^4$ instead of $5x^4$

Comment: How did you get the answer $2x^2$?

Comment: Since $$3\cdot 5 \equiv 1 \pmod 7 \implies {1\over 3} \equiv _7 5$$

Comment: Look, there are only 6 nonzero possibilities. Can you find $n$ with $3n\equiv 5\pmod7$?

Comment: 5/3 in mod 7 equals 2 because 5-3 = 2. I used this method because 1/3 in mod 7 equals 5 as 1-3 = -2 + 7 = 5.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, for any rational $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$, such that $b \ne 0$. We have that $\frac{a}{b} \equiv ab^{-1} \pmod{p}$. In your case, $\frac{5}{3} \equiv 5 \cdot 3^{-1} \pmod{7} = 5 \cdot 5 \pmod{7} = 4 \pmod{7}$. The expression $\frac{5x^{4}}{3x^{2}} \in \mathbb{Z}_{7}[x]$ is equal to $4x^{2}$.